# AWK in Perl?? I have an AWK command line. I don't know how to use it in a Perl script

Tags: perl, awk

My AWK command is:

```
awk'BEGIN {count=0} {count=count+($3-$2)} END {print count}' zebrafish
```

How do I use it in a Perl script?

Comment: I don't see any necessity of using awk within perl. The same functionality can be implemented entirely within perl. Please check my solution

Comment: You can convert an awk script into a perl script using the standard a2p program.

Comment: You could also shorten your `awk` to: `awk '{count+=($3-$2)} END {print count}'`

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any necessity of using `awk` within `perl`. The same functionality can be implemented entirely within `perl` as follows

```
open my $fopen, '<', zebrafish or die $!;
my $count = 0;
while (<$fopen>) {
    $count += $3-$2 if /(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/;
}
print "count = $count\n";
close $fopen;
```

---

If you still want to use `awk`

You can use `system` function to call any shell command, here `awk`, from `Perl` script

```
system("<awk_command>");
```

If you want output of `awk` to store in variable inside `perl` then use

```
my $awk_output = `<awk_command>`;
```

---

On a side note, your `awk` command can be compressed to

```
awk'{count+=($3-$2)} END {print count}' zebrafish
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using Perl and AWK together? Even if the AWK code is already written, if you're extending it with Perl, it probably makes sense to just translate it into Perl. For instance:

```
sub count_diffs($filename) {
  open my $f, "<$filename";
  my $count = 0;
  while (<$f>) {
    my @F = split ' ';
    $count += $F[2]-$F[1];
  }
  return $count;
}

my $count = count_diffs('zebrafish');
```

You can also use the command-line options to write a Perl one-liner that does what the AWK code does:

```
perl -lane '$count += $F[2]-$F[1]; END {print $count}'
```

But in that form it's not significantly easier to embed within a larger Perl program than the AWK code is.

Answer (score 0):

The command in your Perl should be:

```
system("awk 'BEGIN {count =0} {count =count+(\$3-\$2)} END {print count}' zebrafish");
```

Remember to escape the characters `$`, `"`, and I don't know what else with `\`. When in doubt, try to escape; that's the philosophy.

Comment: Thanks. Actually what i have is a long gene file with many columns and rows.I wish to subtract 2nd column of each row from third column and add them all. Is this command fine?If not, how do I write a perl script for that?

Comment: I try it on this file:  
$ cat zebrafish  
11 222 444 555  (EOR)
222 444 555 666 (EOF) 
Inside perl script  
system("awk 'BEGIN {count =0} {count =count+(\$3-\$2)} END {print count}' zebrafish");  
result:  
333
It Works!

Comment: Thanks again. What i have is: Column 2: 1 ,2,3 and column 3 is 4,5,6....What i need is ((4-1)+(5-2)+(6-3))....

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
system("command here"); #will return 0 on success  
#or
open my $out,"command here |"; while(my $line=<$out>){print $line;} 
#or   
my $out=`command`;
#or
exec("command here"); #probably you don't want it!
```

Answer (score 0):

When Perl first came about, it was used as more powerful awk replacement.

Because of this need, Perl actually comes with utility `a2p`, which is designed just for this purpose - it stands for `awk to perl`.

I tried to save your script into a file, and run it through `a2p`, and it worked fine - generated working Perl script. It was not very short (about 20 lines), but it worked.